# Generating XML in .Net

Tags: c#, xml

I am trying to generate XML in the following format:

```
<ImportSession>
  <Batches>
    <Batch>
      <BatchFields>
        <BatchField Name="Field1" Value="1" />
        <BatchField Name="Field2" Value="2" />
        <BatchField Name="Field3" Value="3" />
      </BatchFields>
    <Batch>
  <Batches>
</ImportSession>
```

I have the following code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement importSession = doc.CreateElement("ImportSession");
XmlElement batches = doc.CreateElement("Batches");
XmlElement batch = doc.CreateElement("Batch");
XmlElement batchFields = doc.CreateElement("BatchField");
doc.AppendChild(importSession);

XmlNode importSessionNode = doc.FirstChild;
importSessionNode.AppendChild(batches);

XmlNode batchesNode = importSessionNode.FirstChild;
batchesNode.AppendChild(batch);
XmlNode batchNode = batchesNode.FirstChild;

int numBatchFields = 9;
for (int j = 0; j < numBatchFields; j++)
{
    batchNode.AppendChild(batchFields);

    XmlElement batchfields = (XmlElement)batchNode.FirstChild;
    batchfields.SetAttribute("Name", "BatchPrevSplit");
    batchfields.SetAttribute("Value", j.ToString());
}
```

My problem is that It doesnt add the batchfield tags. It adds one so I get:

```
<ImportSession>
  <Batches>
    <Batch>
      <BatchField Name="BatchPrevSplit" Value="8" />
    </Batch>
  </Batches>
</ImportSession>
```

It seems because I am trying to add the same Child element to the batchNode Node that it just overwrites the data in the existing tag.
I tried putting in

```
XmlElement batchfields = (XmlElement)batchNode.ChildNodes.Item(j);
```

instead of

```
XmlElement batchfields = (XmlElement)batchNode.FirstChild;
```

but it doesnt append another Child to the batchNode if i use the same element so there is only 1 child. So can anyone tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: Why are you doing it in this fashion? Can you not do with with Serialization ?

Comment: Im generating an xml that will be imported into an application and it expects a specific format. The batchfields need to be in that format

Comment: `XmlElement batchFields = doc.CreateElement("BatchField");` shouldn't that be BatchField**s**? Looks like you are missing an element, this one is named wrong, and you need to add a BatchField element.

Comment: I don't think it's worthy of an answer by itself, but if you're interested in using serialization, you can use http://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/ to generate class definitions that can be serialized into the desired XML format.  There's a similar one for JSON: http://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your `for` loop like this:

```
for (int j = 0; j < numBatchFields; j++)
{
    XmlElement batchFields = doc.CreateElement("BatchField");
    batchFields.SetAttribute("Name", "BatchPrevSplit");
    batchFields.SetAttribute("Value", j.ToString());

    batchNode.AppendChild(batchFields);
}
```

Comment: I think you accidentally a line.  ;)

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Thanks!

Comment: Great man thanks. Make a lot of sense. Changing the information before appending so the tag will be different. Cheers

Answer (score 3):

LINQ to XML will save you pain...

```
var xml = new XElement("ImportSession",
    new XElement("Batches",
            new XElement("Batch",
                new XElement("BatchFields",
                    from j in Enumerable.Range(0,9)
                    select new XElement("BatchField",
                        new XAttribute("Name", string.Format("Field{0}", j)),
                        new XAttribute("Value", j)
                        )
                    )
                )
        )
    );
```

Comment: I was initially using that but there are 100 meta data fields so it just got too big and awkward, id rather do it programmatically.

Comment: That's up to you... you can easily do linq with conditional logic as well.  `xElement.Add(new XAttribute("attr", val))`

Comment: @discodowney That statement doesn't make any sense.  Linq to XML is just a different (and better) DOM for working with XML.  Anything you can do with the old DOM you can usually do with less code in Linq to XML.

Comment: yeah your right. I misread his post. Sorry. I didnt know you could do the Enumerable thing. That is a better approach.